# grid of png files - how to display just the images

Tags: css, image, html, styles

I'm trying to put a grid of images (png's) on the screen. I'm using div tags to arrange the pngs in rows and then the rows in columns of rows to show the grid. My problem is that I cannot get rid of a space that appears under every png. Together all the spaces make up a line under the images. I want to get rid of this line. For the purposes of this question I have made a grid of 2 x 2 but it is in fact larger.

```
<div style="display:block;font-size:3px">
<div style="display:inline; min-height:3px; height:8px">
<img src="//some-source.png"><img src="//some-source.png"></div>
<div style="display:inline; min-height:3px; height:8px">
<img src="//some-source.png"><img src="//some-source.png"></div>
<div style="display:inline; min-height:3px; height:8px">
<img src="//some-source.png"><img src="//some-source.png"></div>
</div>
```

How would I style these divs so that the grid is only the pngs, no background image at all? I specified a font-size of 3px and this allowed me to use a png of small size.

Comment: use `img { vertical-align: middle }` to remove the vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

Set padding and margins to 0:

```
img 
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```